# PHP page with embedded HTML displaying extra column

Tags: php

I've a php page with embedded HTML and I'm displaying data from a MySQL database.  PHP is echoing the html inside the php page. All of the data is being returned; however, the data table is being displayed with an extra column and the data that should be in the last column is displayed in the extra column (e.g. my last name is 'Last Name,' but there is an extra column after 'Last Name' with the 'last name' data).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

**get_records.php**

```
            //make connection
            $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            //select db
            mysql_select_db('kis');

            if (!$conn) {
                die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());

            }
            //select db and run query
            mysql_select_db('kis');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
            $records = mysql_query($sql);



            ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/TableCSSCode.css" media="all"/>
                <title>Volunteer Data</title>

            </head>

            <body>


            <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
                <h1>Volunteer Records</h1>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Middle Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                        //loop through the records and display in page
                        while ($users = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $users['firstname'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $users['middlename'] . "<td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $users['lastname'] . "<td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }//end while


                        ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <!--end #dr_container-->

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please migrate to mysqli or PDO. MySQL is deprceated and not recommended.

Comment: Your HTML syntax is wrong. Instead of closing <td> you are again opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have not properly closed your `td` tags:

   ```
   echo "<td>" . $users['middlename'] . "<td>";
   echo "<td>" . $users['lastname'] . "<td>";
   ```

   It should be `</td>` at the end.
2. You're echoing the row tags (`<tr>`). So, don't add additional ones in the plain html (just around your PHP code).

Comment: Thanks Callidior.  Wasn't sure about the additional <td> tags in the html part, but I saw someone else do it that way. You're right, it isn't necessary.  Everything is working well now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the td's

```
echo "<td>" . $users['middlename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $users['lastname'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Close "td" tag.
2. Remove "tr" tags before and after where php code start because there are already tr tags inside the php code. 
   Following is the updated HTML of table:

   ```
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Middle Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
       </tr>
       <?php
           //loop through the records and display in page
           while ($users = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>" . $users['firstname'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $users['middlename'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $users['lastname'] . "</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }//end while
       ?>
   ```